# Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'fisierUrl' of undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I create a react app and i want to fetch data (images urls)from my API.
in Detali .js i wrote this code:
Detalii.js

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { useParams } from "react-router-dom";
import url from "../url";
import Header from "../components/Header";

const Detalii = () => {
  const [info, setInfo] = useState({});
  const { id } = useParams();
  useEffect(() => {
    async function getData() {
      try {
        const res = await fetch(`${url}/detalii/${id}`);
        const data = await res.json();
        setInfo(data);
      } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
      }
    }
    getData();
  }, [id]);
  //console.log(info);
  return (
    <div className="bg-detalii">
      <Header info={info} />
    </div>
  );
};
export default Detalii;
```

in Header conponent i display image like this:
Header.js:

```
import React from "react";

const Header = ({ info }) => {
  console.log(info);
  return (
    <div className="header">
      <img src={info.fisier.fisierUrl} className="img-detalii" alt="poza" />
      <p className="text-detalii">{info.nume}</p>
    </div>
  );
};
export default Header;
```

in my console `info.fisier` object is like this:
[image: console output]

in Detali.js it shows me the error when it displays image.how to fix it? thanks

Comment: I only see a `console.log(info)` but no `console.log(info.fisier)`

Comment: in the image it's output from `console.log(info.fisier)`

Comment: can you also post the code for that `console.log` - especially the location of it

Answer (score 2):

look at the `src={info.fisier.fisierUrl}` especially at `info.fisier.fisierUrl`.

At the beginning your request is in progress and your `info` is equal to `{}`.

So it's `{}.fisier.fisierUrl`. `{}.fisier` is `undefined`. And `undefined.fisierUrl` throws an error

How to fix:

Instead of `src={info.fisier.fisierUrl}` try `src={info && info.fisier && info.fisier.fisierUrl}`

Answer (score 1):

I believe the issue is that you try to render `<Header />` before the fetch call has returned and `setInfo` has been called.

One solution could be to render `Header` only when info is "truthy". I.e.

```
return (
    <div className="bg-detalii">
      {info && (<Header info={info} />)}
    </div>
  );
```